# Insert column with Max in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I did not know how to insert column with max.

```
Select id,MAX(salary),Min(Salary)
from C 
GROUP BY id;
```

it is give me the all id with it is maximum 
 and I want just the id with maximum and minimum of salary!!

Comment: what if two id's share the maximum? Do you want both?

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Yes, I do. And I wanna it with both max and min together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select id,
salary 
from C 
where salary = (select MAX(salary) 
                  from C)
```

Comment: + it's possible that more than one record will be returned with different id but same salary

Comment: if I want to add minimum with it , it is not working why?

Comment: @SarahAH because you probably added it with `AND salary = (select MIN(salary) from C`, where you ened to do it with `OR ...`. If that's not the case we will need you to show us what you did so we can fix it ;)

Comment: @SarahAH If you keep adding `SELECT` statements like that then it will increase the number of table scans the query has to do and make it much less efficient. You can get the answer with only a single table scan - although not using this answer.

Comment: @MT0 If someone is asking this question then keeping it simple is probably way more important then the number of table scans.

Comment: @JBrooks I dunno, I'm of the opinion that you might as well point out the pros and cons of each solutions. In this case, one solution is much easier to edit (by being more entry-level) and the other executes more swiftly.

Answer (score 3):

Several options for you that only require a single scan of the table:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8541/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE C ( ID, SALARY ) AS
          SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 110 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 110 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,  90 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1 - Get a single ID**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT ID, SALARY
   FROM   c
   ORDER BY SALARY DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8541/9/0)**:

```
| ID | SALARY |
|----|--------|
|  2 |    110 |
```

**Query 2 - Get a single ID (alternate method that will get min and max IDs)**:

```
SELECT MAX( ID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY SALARY ) AS MAX_SALARY_ID,
       MAX( SALARY ) AS MAX_SALARY,
       MIN( ID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY SALARY ) AS MIN_SALARY_ID,
       MIN( SALARY ) AS MIN_SALARY
FROM   C
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8541/9/1)**:

```
| MAX_SALARY_ID | MAX_SALARY | MIN_SALARY_ID | MIN_SALARY |
|---------------|------------|---------------|------------|
|             4 |        110 |             5 |         90 |
```

**Query 3 - Get all the IDs with the maximum salary**:

```
SELECT ID, SALARY
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         SALARY,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SALARY DESC ) AS RNK
  FROM   C
)
WHERE  RNK = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8541/9/2)**:

```
| ID | SALARY |
|----|--------|
|  2 |    110 |
|  4 |    110 |
```

**Query 4 - Get all IDs for min and max salary**:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( CASE MIN_RANK WHEN 1 THEN ID END, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ID ) AS MIN_SALARY_IDS,
       MAX( CASE MIN_RANK WHEN 1 THEN SALARY END ) AS MIN_SALARY,
       LISTAGG( CASE MAX_RANK WHEN 1 THEN ID END, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ID ) AS MAX_SALARY_IDS,
       MAX( CASE MAX_RANK WHEN 1 THEN SALARY END ) AS MAX_SALARY
FROM (
  SELECT ID,
         SALARY,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SALARY  ASC ) AS MIN_RANK,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SALARY DESC ) AS MAX_RANK
  FROM   C
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8541/9/3)**:

```
| MIN_SALARY_IDS | MIN_SALARY | MAX_SALARY_IDS | MAX_SALARY |
|----------------|------------|----------------|------------|
|              5 |         90 |            2,4 |        110 |
```

**Query 5**:

```
SELECT ID,
       SALARY,
       CASE WHEN MIN_RANK = 1 THEN 'MIN'
            WHEN MAX_RANK = 1 THEN 'MAX' END AS MIN_MAX  
FROM (
  SELECT ID,
         SALARY,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SALARY  ASC ) AS MIN_RANK,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY SALARY DESC ) AS MAX_RANK
  FROM   C
)
WHERE MIN_RANK = 1 OR MAX_RANK = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8541/9/4)**:

```
| ID | SALARY | MIN_MAX |
|----|--------|---------|
|  2 |    110 |     MAX |
|  4 |    110 |     MAX |
|  5 |     90 |     MIN |
```

Comment: Why did you opt for non-atomic data for your query #4?

Comment: @JulienBlanchard - because there is an indeterminate and unequal number of rows for minimum and maximum values.

Comment: Well, I was more suggesting having X rows, with 1 ID per row (do 3 rows, 2 max and 1 min in this case). Just to keep the results atomic.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard I was just updating it to do that when you posted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `first_value` or `last_value`

> The FIRST_VALUE analytic function is similar to the FIRST analytic
>   function, allowing you to return the first result from an ordered set.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions

```
create table C (id int, salary int);
insert into c values(1, 1);
insert into c values(2, 2);
insert into c values(3, 3);
insert into c values(4, 4);
insert into c values(5, 5);

Select distinct first_value(id) over ( order by salary desc)
from C 

    FIRST_VALUE(ID)OVER(ORDERBYSAL
1   5
```